# batch application (JSR 352)

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, xsd, java-ee-8, jsr

I'm beginner with development of batch and I want to create my first batch 
so I create a maven project on intellij my problem with the xml file 
is the tag  not recognized by intellij and say 'element job must be declared' 
I think the problem is xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" point to C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.6\plugins\JSF\lib as you can see in the screenshot and not to 
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.6\plugins\BatchApplications\lib
[image]
Thanks

Comment: Did you try with IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 release: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html) includes the updated resources that should fix this issue.